# German citizen travelling in Canada - can I enter the US for a short trip to Seattle?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, us-visa-waiver-program, german-citizens

I'm a German citizen travelling in British Columbia, Canada – I would like to enter the US for a short trip to Seattle.

I did this a few years back where I just went up to the border, filled in a form and was good to go for a few days, but I don't know how it is now because they changed some of their rules to enter the US, I think.

Comment: When was "a few years back"? There were some changes with [the I-94 form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_I-94) (which is not a paper form anymore if you arrive by air or sea) and some restrictions for people who have been to Iran, Iraq, Sudan or Syria (or are citizens of one of these countries) but I don't think anything changed recently for a German citizen entering from Canada (except if you are also a citizen of Iran, Iraq, Sudan or Syria, obviously).

Comment: Few years back was like 3 years ago.. ok perfect sounds good!

Answer (score 7):

It would depend on how you intend to arrive in Seattle but if you [cross the border by land](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1258/~/esta---traveling-to-u.s.-by-land) all you will need to have with you is your German passport.

But an ESTA may be a nice to have just for your own peace of mind.

Comment: Don't forget the US$6 he may need to pay for the I-94W. I have heard that ESTA holders with finger prints already on file sometimes get waved through the land border without that, though I don't know the exact conditions that allow this.